# Creating an Outlook Office Addin Using Yeoman, does it work on the installed Outlook application too?

Tags: xml, outlook, yeoman, office-addins

I've done some research on how to go about programming an Outlook Office Addin and as far as I can see, there are two ways. One, is using C# in Visual Studio and the other is using Yeoman to generate a project that includes HTML and XML.

I'm more familiar with the Yeoman way, however I need to be able to program and install it on an application on the computer as opposed to the outlook website. I know that you can install an Addin on the Store, but I'm wondering how it works with accessing data from within the computer Outlook application.

My project is to take calendar data for a team of workers and specify a location for a requested job, then find the worker that is closest to that location and display when they are available.

I think the question I'm trying to ask here is, would it be possible to create and deploy this Addin using the Yeoman method? If so, how would it be possible to go about getting the calendar data from the application? Any answers or information that people could give would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply but I just stumbled on your question while looking for something similar.

Indeed you can run a yeoman-generated Outlook add-in in the desktop (as opposed to web) version of Outlook. You just need to "sideload" it, as per the instructions in "Sideload an add-in in Outlook on the desktop" here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing#sideload-an-add-in-in-outlook-on-the-desktop

As far as "getting the calendar data from the application," you would still use the Office Javascript API on the desktop, exactly as you would on the web.

Hope that helps anyone else passing by this way!